# как убрать тень под кнопкой во время прокручивание scrollview

Tags: python, android, kivy, app, kivymd

```
ScrollView:
    bar_width: 0
    #do_scroll_y: True
    #scroll_y: 1
    MDGridLayout:
        adaptive_height: True
        #size_hint_y: None
        cols: 1
        height: "750dp"
        padding: "20dp","20dp","20dp","20dp"
        spacing: '12dp'
        PlayerListItem:
            MDLabel:
                text: '3'
            MDFloatingActionButton:
                on_press: root.play()
        PlayerListItem:
            MDLabel:
                text: '2'
            MDFloatingActionButton:
                on_press: root.play2()
        PlayerListItem:
            MDLabel:
                text: '1'
            MDFloatingActionButton:
                on_press: root.play3()
```

Comment: вы все уебки ебаные на простой вопрос не могут ответить скатины